# Facebook FQL: When querying sometimes the media attachment returns a large and small image, sometimes just small

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

When executing an FQL query the `attachments > media > photo` section has an array called 'images'. Usually this includes two items, the small version and the large. However, occasionally it just includes the small version. I know a large version is there because it is visible on the feed. This seems arbitrary as to when this occurs. What would make the feed only return the small version?

Here's the FQL query I'm using:

```sql
SELECT type,
       created_time,
       message,
       attachment
FROM   stream
WHERE  source_id = 00000000000
       AND message != ""
       AND is_hidden = 0
       AND type > 0
LIMIT 1
```